# What is new in mongodb server monitoring and discovery ? What were the limitation of old one ? How did they overcome now?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update my node-mongodb-native, but it is asking me to add useUnifiedTopology option. I just want to know what were the issues were old monitoring tools and how they were solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useUnifiedTopology` option was introduced in the MongoDB 3.2.1 Node.js driver and will become the default behaviour in the 4.x driver release later this year. This represents a change to the Node driver's Server Discovery and Monitoring (SDAM) implementation rather than a change to the [MongoDB SDAM specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring-monitoring.rst#sdam-monitoring-specification).

The [3.2.1 release notes](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v3.2.1) includes an overview of the changes:

> In this release we are very excited to announce the immediate availability of a complete rewrite of the driver's "topology" layer. This is the core brains of the driver responsible for things like server selection, server discovery and monitoring. This work combines the three existing topology concepts (`Mongos`, `ReplSet`, and `Server`) into a single type `Topology`. The new `Topology` type uses the same machinery to represent all three types, greatly improving our ability to maintain the code, and reducing the chance for bug duplication.
>
> The Topology class no longer uses a callback store, instead relying on a server selection loop for operation execution. This means failed operations will fail faster, with more accurate stack traces and specifics about the failure. It generally makes it much easier to reason about what the driver is doing each time an operation is executed.

There are also some features in newer 3.x Node driver releases that require the `useUnifiedTopology` option, such as the [SRV Polling for Sharded Clusters](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v3.3.0) introduced in v3.3.0.